# facet_wrap with different factor levels in each subplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Is there any possibility to remove "f e d" levels from the first subplot and "c b a" from the second subplot using `facet_wrap`? In other words I want to have only "c b a" columns on first subplot and only "f e d" columns on the 2nd.

Example data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:6], gr = c(rep("kk", 3), rep("yy", 3)), v = 10:15)
```

Plot call:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = v)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~gr, nrow = 2)
```

[image: Current result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a fixed scale for your y-axis, simply add `scales = "free_y"` to your `facet_wrap()` command.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = v)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~gr, nrow = 2, scales = "free_y")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Haven't thought about "free_y" options in such context before.